# Go to a specific relative number line in Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to use relative line numbers with NeoVim to jump through my file so I am expecting to digit to jump 20 lines before:

```
:20k
```

and to jump 20 lines after:

```
:20j
```

I tried but nothing happens.

So I tried to add this configuration to my init.v file:

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'
```

But when I insert something like: `:20j` it gives me this error:

```
E471: Argument required
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by learning properly how to use your tools. I don't know if Neovim still has it but Vim comes with `$ vimtutor` for the basics and you can still probably follow `:help user-manual`.

Case in point, it is `20j`, not `:20j`.

Comment: `:Tutor` the Neovim tutorial.